# Android - Send local file via HTTP post

Tags: android, file, storage, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to send a local file (**music or video only**) via HTTP post with this line

```
InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
   new FileInputStream(file), -1);
```

However, first I need to get a File object that corresponds to the file. I use an Intent to pick a file. In my `onActivityResult()`, I'm able to retrieve the Intent data. When doing `data.getData()`, I obtain a path that looks like `content://....` I tried many things with the method `getContentResolver` (from `Activity`), but I can't make it work.

Can any one tell me what's wrong on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily make a `Uri` to `InputStream` without `File` object, just call `getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri);` in your activity.

Comment: Yes I know this, but then how can I send it via HTTP POST?

Comment: well, what kinds of way do you send data? ``HttpURLConnection`` or ``HttpClient``?

Comment: HttpClient with HttpPost

Comment: You need to download a jar file httpmime-versionxx.jar, use ``MultipartEntity`` to do the fileupload. call ``multipartEntity.addPart("param_name", new InputStreamBody(inputsream, filename));``, their are many samples on the net. forgive my english...

Comment: I don't want t use any extra jar because all I need is already packaged in Android. I just don't know how to make it work.

Comment: in your code, ``-1`` means what? the file' s size? I prefer to use ``HttpURLConnection``. But I suppose use the ``HttpClient`` is similar. ``HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);`` ``InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri))``, ``httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);`` ``reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");`` ``HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);`` and then resolve the result. I did' t test it. but you can hava a try...

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the `HTTP POST` protocol by using the `setRequestMethod`, such as:
`httpconn.setRequestMethod(POST)`

Also have you tried this solution?

[**Uploading files to HTTP server using POST on Android.**](http://stunningco.de/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/)

Comment: Yes thanks I already know this. My problem is: how to pick a local file in order to send it (video or music)?